# twitter auth 400 bad request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

twitter auth を使用したRailsアプリケーションをherokuにアップロード後、'auth/twitter'へのボタンを押すと
We're sorry, but something went wrong.という画面が出ます。

herokuのログを見てみると、

```
Started GET "/auth/twitter" for ***.**.***.** at 015-10-22 03:19:23 +0000

OAuth::Unauthorized (400 Bad Request):

vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/oauth-0.4.7/lib/oauth/consumer.rb:216:in `token_request'
...
015-10-22T03:19:23.433349+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/auth/twitter" host=*******.herokuapp.com request_id=*** fwd="***" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=103ms status=500 bytes=1754
```

と出力されます。
ローカルの開発環境では問題なく動作するため、リンクの指定等、プログラムには問題ないのではと踏んでいます。
`heroku run rake db:migrate`も何度も試しましたが、うまく動作しません。

お力添えお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku用のTwitter appを新たに作成し、Twitter app側もRails側もHeroku用の設定を施す必要があります。

具体的には

- Rails側でHeroku用Twitter appのkeyやsecretを使っているか（ちゃんと値が設定されているか）
- Twitter app側でHeroku用のコールバックURLが指定されているか

このあたりをしっかり確認する必要があると思います。

下記のページも参考になるかもしれません。

[gem 'omniauth-twitter'で認証しようとしてOAuth::Unauthorized 401 Unauthorizedなんてエラーがでたら - Qiita](http://qiita.com/hirokishirai/items/5a43977a38ecd922bfb9)

それでもダメであれば、具体的に試行錯誤した内容やその結果、Twitter関連のコード、スタックトレースの全体等を追記してください。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
作ったアプリケーションが正常に動きました。とても嬉しいです。
Heroku用のTwitter appを新たに作成した後、提示していただいた
リンクのリンクを元に解決いたしました。(heroku に環境変数を追加する)